# Как кодировать audio файл в строку Base64?

Tags: java, android

Я загружаю файл audio через onActivityResult(), мне нужно его отправить на сервер (php) с помощью библиотеки volley. Как мне кодировать audio в строку base64.

Comment: 1) Из файла получить байтовый массив 2) Кодировать байтовый массив через `Base64.encodeToString` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7360440/5909792)

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так, наверное.

```
public class AudioToBase64 {

private File file;

public AudioToBase64(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}

// Например аудиофайл с SD-карты
// private File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/имя_файла.wav");

public String getBase64String() {

    String encoded = "";

    try {

        byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file); // Переводим в байты
        encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0); // Переводим в Base64

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        encoded = e.getMessage();
    }

    return encoded;
}
}
```